# Automatic Full-Screen Mode for Windows UWP C++/CX Application

Tags: windows, uwp, visual-studio-2019, c++-cx

I'm working on a Windows UWP (Universal Windows Platform) C++/CX Application. I would like for this application to be full-screen from the moment that it launches, rather than briefly not full-screen and then changed to full-screen later. Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: Before a window (or anything else) is shown, detect available full screen video modes - then pick one and switch to it, then show your gui.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Right, but I don't know how to write the code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue. I start my `App::OnLaunched()` function as follows:

```
void App::OnLaunched(Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation::LaunchActivatedEventArgs^ e)
{
    ApplicationView^ view = ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView();

    Windows::Foundation::Rect r;
    Windows::Foundation::Size sz;
    //view->SetPreferredMinSize(r)
    bool b = view->TryEnterFullScreenMode();
    int c = 0;
    while (b == false) {
        b = view->TryEnterFullScreenMode();
        c++;
        if (c == 100) {
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    r = view->VisibleBounds;
    sz = Windows::Foundation::Size(r.Width, r.Height);
    view->SetPreferredMinSize(sz);
    .....
```

The code continually tries to set the window as full-screen, and exits if it cannot achieve this. Then once the window is full-screen, the code sets the preferred minimum window size to the dimensions of the full-screen.

But that's not sufficient, because the application (or more precisely, the splash screen) starts in not-full-screen mode and then shifts to full-screen mode later.

So the last thing is to adjust the application's splash-screen in `Package.appxmanifest`. I created a large 2480x1200 monochrome image using the photo editor GIMP, and then used this as my splash-screen image in `Package.appxmanifest`. I then ensure that only the "Scale400" (the 2480x1200 scaled version) of this PNG is the only "SplashScreen..." image present in my `Assets\` directory.

And with all of these changes, the application (splash-screen included) is full-screen from the moment it is launched.

Answer (score 2):

The ApplicationView.TryEnterFullScreenMode method attempts to switch the application to full-screen mode. You can call this method in the OnActivated event handler of your application's main page.

code

```
void MainPage::OnActivated(Object^ sender, ActivationArguments^ args)
{
    ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView()->TryEnterFullScreenMode();
}
```

Comment: I don't think I can implemented this function. I'm getting a "inherited member is not allowed" compile-time error when I try to implement it. I think it's because this is a protected function.

Comment: You can add the code after `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: When I try to do that, calling ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView() throws a Element Not Found Exception.